# How to apply depth test to diffuse lighting?

Tags: vulkan

I've been fiddling my way through vulkan, and have tried out some basic diffuse lighting, which only takes into account the surface normals. On the side of the model facing the light, things look fine -

[image: The side facing the light.]

On the opposite side of the model though, there's a part of the model which is shaded like it is illuminated even though it shouldn't be-

[image: Notice how the shutter seems illuminated]

I know this happens because I'm only considering the surface normals and the shader doesn't care where the vertex is as long as its normal is towards the light, but how do I fix it? I feel like I need a way to do a depth test to figure out whether a part of the model should be lighted or not. How would I go about doing this if that is the case? What should I be doing if otherwise?

Comment: Go back to the front of the house, which is lit. Now move your camera gradually backward away from the house, still pointing to the house. Do you want the house to become darker? Or did you mean something else by "depth check"?

Comment: I meant that parts of the model obscured by other parts facing the light  shouldn't be shaded as though they were illuminated. Maybe depth check isn't the word for it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sounds like you want to implement shadows.

A standard way is [shadow mapping](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shadow_mapping). You render the scene from the point of the light and only keep the depth buffer. You then pass that depth buffer as a texture to the fragment shader and sample that based on where the point is in the world and compare the sampled depth with the distance to the light.

However there are various caveats with this technique. Most common ones being shadow acne where quantization error leads to fragments self shadowing resulting in speckled lighting, you can fix that by adding a small offset to the depth. The next one is peter panning, where that offset you added previously leads to light bleedthrough where a thin wall meets a floor, you fix that by not having walls thin enough that the offset goes through them.

Comment: There is a simpler solution but it isn't as nice as shadow mapping. You first take original vertex normals and check if they are facing light by calculating usual diffuse lighting term. Then, if they do, You perform lighting calculations with vectors read from a normal map. This solution doesn't look as good as shadow mapping but looks better than a raw normal-mapping. As for shadow mapping, there is a [shadow mapping example](https://github.com/PacktPublishing/Vulkan-Cookbook/blob/master/Samples/Source%20Files/11%20Lighting/05-Adding_shadows_to_the_scene/main.cpp) in the Vulkan Cookbook.

Comment: That's what I followed (loosely) for the diffuse lighting. It's a great resource for understanding what things are what  in vulkan.